# Talend ESB deployment on runtime

Tags: runtime, talend, apache-karaf

I'm on Talend ESB Runtime.

I encountered problems while starting ./trun. Nothing on the screen appeared after start. The process is launched but I can't get anything else...

Anyway I tryed to deployed a job, and there is something weird in the log about org.osgi.framework.bundleException in tesb.log.

And Karaf.log is OK

Here tesb.log :
[tesb.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgpGu.png)

karaf.log :
[karaf.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4lUG.png)

log in repository data :
[timestamplog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2woj.png)

I don't know how to investigate, because logs are poor and JVM is equal between Talend ESB and the runtime...

Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you provide the logs?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited the post.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add log files as files (text dump), not as pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You only showed a small snippet of the log. From this I can already see that at least one bundle can not be resolved. This means that this bundle can not be used. In the snippet the bundle seems to be a user bundle but I am pretty sure you have other such log messages that show that one of the main bundles of karaf can not be loaded.

If you want to check for the cause of the problem look into these messages and search for non optional package that are not resolved. Usually this leads to a missing bundle.

If you simply want to get your system running again you can simply reset karaf by using

```
./trun clean
```

Remember though that you then have to reinstall all features again.